# Global pointer to a structure doesn't updated in a function call when trying to access next node. Global pointer returns nil

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, global-variables

Why in the first code any->next and root->next at the free_hashtable returns nil? If I print in the generate function, it does returns an address... So, as the *root is global, why I can't access it?

Also why in the second code when I recursive call a function that have a paramenter pointing to a global structure pointer (so I can navigate throught it), it just gives me the main address, if I try like function(any->next), the returned value is just the same as any not any->next.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const int nodes = 27; // 26 letters + '.
int height = 3;

typedef struct hash_table
{
    char word[46]; // 45 letters + NULL.
    struct hash_table *next;
}
hash_table;

typedef struct trie
{
    bool is_word;
    struct trie *character[nodes];
    hash_table *next;
}
trie;

trie *generate(int times);
void free_hashtable(trie *any, int times);
void free_hashtable2(hash_table *any);
void free_trie(trie *any);

trie *root;

int main(void)
{
    // Generate a trie with a height specified in a variable
    // and also allocate memory to the entire structure.
    root = generate(height);

    free_hashtable(root, height);
    free_trie(root);
    free(root);

    return 0;
}

trie *generate(int times)
{
    // Allocate memory to root, to character[i]
    // and also change the access of character[i] to root.
    // So in the second run, root would be equivalent to
    // root->character[i].
    root = malloc(sizeof(trie));

    //printf("%p\n", root); HERE it gives me an address.
    root->next = NULL;


    if (times > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
        {
            // For every single pointer generates more nodes pointers.
            root->character[i] = generate(times - 1);
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
        {
            // Set all remaining pointers to null
            // as there aren't more arrays.
            root->character[i] = NULL;
        }
        // Malloc for new structure.
        root->next = malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
        root->next->next = NULL;
    }

    // Return the address of root,
    // so the root in the main function can point
    // to the trie created.
    return root;
}

void free_hashtable(trie *any, int times)
{
    printf("%p\n", root->character[0]); // print nil, yet, if I print in the generate function,
    // it does give me an address.

    printf("%p\n", any->character[0]); // returns nil, but why?
    // Shouldn't any = root? and then any->next = root->next?

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
    {
        if (times > 1)
        {
            free_hashtable(any->character[i], times - 1);
        }
    }

    if (times == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
        {
            //Where root is root->character[i]->character[i]
            if (any->character[i]->next->next != NULL)
            {
                free_hashtable2(any->character[i]->next);
            }
            free(any->character[i]->next);
        }
    }

    return;
}

void free_hashtable2(hash_table *any)
{
    if (any->next != NULL)
    {
        free_hashtable2(any->next);
        free(any->next);
    }

    return;
}

void free_trie(trie *any)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
    {
        if (any->character[i] != NULL)
        {
            // Calls function first so it can works backwards.
            free_trie(any->character[i]);
            free(any->character[i]);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test
{
    char word[15];
    struct test *next;
}
test;

test *root;
test *generate(int times);
void free_dummy(test *any);

int main(void)
{
    root = generate(3);
    free_dummy(root);
    free(root);
}

test *generate(int times)
{
    root = malloc(sizeof(test));
    strcpy(root->word, "dummy");
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (times != 0)
    {
        root->next = generate(times - 1);
    }
    if (times == 0)
    {
        root->next = NULL;
    }
    return root;
}

void free_dummy(test *any) // Comes as root.
{
    printf("%p\n", any); // any never updates to root->next, but any is pointing to root. Shouldn't any->next = root->next?
    if (any->next != NULL)
    {
        free_dummy(any->next);
        free(any->next);
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks to everyone! All help is welcome!

Comment: You supplied two programs.  I suggest you revise your question so it's one [mre].   One question per submission please.

Comment: Your first program doesn't compile for me.  Use `#define nodes 27` instead of a `const int`.  Avoid global variables whenever possible.  It also segfaults for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the function `generate()` recursively and two things happens you overwrite the global variable `root = malloc(...)` in each call (leaking memory) and in the last call when when `times == 0` you reset `root->characters[i] = NULL.`

I had to change nodes to a symbolic constant to get your code to compile, and changed height for consistency.

In `generate()` use a local variable `root` instead.  Prefer passing a variable opposed to type to sizeof.  I didn't fix it but you should check that `malloc()` was successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define nodes 27 // 26 letters + '.
#define height 3

typedef struct hash_table {
    char word[46]; // 45 letters + NULL.
    struct hash_table *next;
} hash_table;

typedef struct trie {
    bool is_word;
    struct trie *character[nodes];
    hash_table *next;
} trie;

trie *generate(int times) {
    trie *root = malloc(sizeof *root);
    root->next = NULL;
    if(!times) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
            root->character[i] = NULL;
        root->next = malloc(sizeof *root->next);
        root->next->next = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
        root->character[i] = generate(times - 1);
    return root;
}

void free_hashtable2(hash_table *any) {
    if (!any->next) return;
    free_hashtable2(any->next);
    free(any->next);
}

void free_trie(trie *any) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        if (!any->character[i]) continue;
        free_trie(any->character[i]);
        free(any->character[i]);
    }
}

void free_hashtable(trie *any, int times) {
    printf("%p\n", (void *) any->character[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++)
        if (times > 1)
            free_hashtable(any->character[i], times - 1);
    if (times == 1)
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
            if (any->character[i]->next->next)
                free_hashtable2(any->character[i]->next);
            free(any->character[i]->next);
        }
}

int main(void) {
    trie *root = generate(height);
    free_hashtable(root, height);
    free_trie(root);
    free(root);
}
```

To me, the 3 different free functions is a code smell.  Instead write one free function that does the "opposite" of your builder function `generate()`.

Comment: it is very strange. If I don't use global variable the code works fine. Allocate memory and also frees the memory of everything. The segment fault in this case was caused be a stack overflow, this when I use a global variable. As I have stated, the parameter didn't update, thus, it calls itself forever. The only problem is that a global variable is a must for me right now. But thanks!

Comment: Aaaaa. I Understand now.

I had a similar function that creates a structure calling itself, the only difference is that the variable wasn't global, so I could declare a local variable every time I enter the function.